# Image type in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, image, sqlite

What is the column type for an image to be stored in the database? And how do I handle the transmission of the image from the database to and from the client side of the application?

Comment: Database? Which database, SQLServer, Oracle, MySql...?

Comment: Is it different for different databases? I'm using sqlite now, but i'll probably move to MySql in the future...

Comment: Yes, because for SQL Server and SQL CE its Image DataType. For Oracle I think we need to use BLOB

Comment: ok well I'm using sqlite and mysql

Answer (score 0):

use column type byte array, transform image to bytes for storing in database and vice verse